# How to make child divs use all available space when one makes the container scroll?

Tags: html, css

I have a few divs like so:

```css
.item {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.item:hover {
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
}
.container {
  max-width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">somewhat short item 1</div>
  <div class="item">somewhat short item 2</div>
  <div class="item">somewhat short item 3</div>
  <div class="item">very long item that makes the container scroll</div>
  <div class="item">somewhat short item 4</div>
  <div class="item">somewhat short item 5</div>
  <div class="item">somewhat short item 6</div>
  <div class="item">somewhat short item 7</div>
</div>
```

The longer div makes the container scroll, as it should. However, because the width of the container is not increased, the hover is cut off at the point where the scrolling started:

[image]

I would like all divs to extend to the end of the scrollable area, so that the hover is not cut off like that.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`display:grid` on the container can do it

```css
.item {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.item:hover {
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
}
.container {
  max-width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  display:grid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">somewhat short item 1</div>
  <div class="item">somewhat short item 2</div>
  <div class="item">somewhat short item 3</div>
  <div class="item">very long item that makes the container scroll</div>
  <div class="item">somewhat short item 4</div>
  <div class="item">somewhat short item 5</div>
  <div class="item">somewhat short item 6</div>
  <div class="item">somewhat short item 7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: [note for me: need to find the duplicate]